# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized using Sharepoint in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, unauthorized

I am trying to read files from Sharepoint. I have used the following codes:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

namespace VLCPlayer
{
    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string url = "https://share.philips.com/sites/STS020170405131503/";
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url);
            var password = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in "passwor".ToCharArray()) 
            { password.AppendChar(c); }
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = ctx.Web;

            ctx.Load(web);

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the Exception:

```
WebException was unhandled:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (401) 
Unauthorized.
```

However, I can access the site using the same credentials in the browser. Please note that I am using username "username@companyname.com" and my username also includes a dot in it. I am afraid whether something is wrong with my username but I can access my site using the exactly same username. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.